# Select entre datas no Mysql

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde,

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho uma coluna *DATA_ENTRADA* do tipo data e preciso de um select que compare a *DATA_ENTRADA* e a "**data atual**" ( ex: hoje é 28/08/2015, amanhã seria 29/08/2015 ), e me retorne apenas os registros com a *data_entrada* >= 90 dias

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço, já tentei de tudo mas sem sucesso.

Comment: tudo que pesquisei me remeteu ao between, mas só consigo consultas entre datas específicas, e o que eu preciso é datas > 90 dias, comparando a data_entrada e a data atual.

Comment: Alguém testou a minha resposta, porque só eu não ganhei +1 ? isso magoa.... se eu tivesse como votar na minha própria resposta eu votaria...rsrsrrs

Comment: @mayconrocha você quer a partir da data atual now() curdate() os registros que estiverem 90 dias após ou 90 dias anteriores, porque tem 2 respostas p/ cada interpretação

Answer (score 8):

Basta calcular a diferença entre o campo desejado e a data atual (`now`) no where.

Como não está bem claro o que você quer, então seguem as duas possiveis soluções:

**90 dias anteriores a "hoje"**

```
SELECT * FROM dados WHERE DATEDIFF(now(), data_entrada) >= 90
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e92f0/2).

**90 dias após "hoje"**

```
SELECT * FROM dados WHERE DATEDIFF(data_entrada, now()) >= 90
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e92f0/1).

Basta alterar a ordem dos parâmetros do `DATEDIFF` que resolve ambos os problemas.

Comment: Não entendi o porque do negativo, qual o problema com a resposta?

Comment: Vou mudar denovo p/ down, seus insert são todos com data menores que 90 dias a partir de hoje então não poderia trazer resultados, pelo que entendi da pergunta.

Comment: Li de volta a pergunta e realmente está ambíguo.

Comment: Então fica o meu down mesmo, o seu Fiddle esta dando retorno 1 de maio e 25 abril, e ao meo ver teria que retornar somente datas para frente de 28 de agosto que é o now() ou curdate() ou a tal data atual

Comment: Editei com as duas possíveis resposta @SneepSNinjA

Comment: rsrsrs apesar de você não inserir no Fiddle registros com data maiores que 90 dias posteriores... vou dar o +1 porque em si o SQL esta correto, tanto p/ mais quanto p/ menos

Answer (score 6):

```
WHERE DATE_SUB(data_atual,INTERVAL 90 DAY) >= data_entrada
```

Isso retorna apenas as datas que estão 90 dias ou mais antes da data atual

Comment: sua consulta também não retorna resultados segue teste http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d38e/3 deveria retornar 2 registros conforme teste, o AP quer 90 após a data atual curdate() ou now() pelo que entendi, se for 90 anteriores a data atual eu vou reverter ok

Answer (score 5):

```
select * from suaTabela where data_entrada >= DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL 90 DAY);
```

**Explicação:** `DATE_ADD( param1, INTERVAL 90 DAY )`, onde `param1` seria a data atual e o segundo parâmetro seria a quantidade de dias que no caso é 90.

Fiz um Fork Luis Henrique para explicar a divergência no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d38e/1) até onde eu entendi a partir do `now()` ou `curdate()` que seria data atual os registros maiores que 90 dias.

Comment: +1 pelo fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou usar o `CURDATE() + INTERVAL 90 DAY`?

Comment: Olá Gustavo! Edita sua resposta para ficar mais com cara de resposta do que comentário :)