# Como retornar alguns* dados com intervalo de tempo?

Tags: mysql

Tenho um sistema de monitoramento. Recupera a localização do usuário a cada 5 segundos. No entanto, eu quero mostrar apenas os registros que aparecem no intervalo a cada 15 segundos(por exemplo). A ideia principal é que seja dinâmico, onde o usuário do sistema possa fazer essa alternância, sendo 10, 15, 20 ou 60, etc.  Um dos filtros seria a data de início e data de término para buscar esses registros. Vejam a seguinte tabela abaixo:

```
+------------+-------------------+
|     ID     |       data        |
+------------+-------------------+
|     1      |2017-07-10 10:11:10|
+------------+-------------------+
|     2      |2017-07-10 10:11:15|
+------------+-------------------+
|     3      |2017-07-10 10:11:20|
+------------+-------------------+
|     4      |2017-07-10 10:11:25|
+------------+-------------------+
|     5      |2017-07-10 10:11:30|
+------------+-------------------+
|     6      |2017-07-10 10:11:35|
+------------+-------------------+
|     7      |2017-07-10 10:11:44|
+------------+-------------------+
|     8      |2017-07-10 10:12:18|
+------------+-------------------+
```

Gostaria de uma *query* que me retorne somente os dados que tenha diferença de 15 segundos (por exemplo) entre a data anterior. Para este exemplo acima, me retornaria as seguintes linhas:

```
+------------+-------------------+
|     ID     |       data        |
+------------+-------------------+
|     1      |2017-07-10 10:11:10|
+------------+-------------------+
|     4      |2017-07-10 10:11:25|
+------------+-------------------+
|     7      |2017-07-10 10:11:40|
+------------+-------------------+
|     8      |2017-07-10 10:12:18|
+------------+-------------------+
```

Não quero que me retorne [todos os dados do banco em um intervalo de data](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83199/select-entre-datas-no-mysql), mas sim retornar apenas alguns dados saltando algumas linhas baseando em um tempo, por exemplo de, 15 segundos.

Como seria essa *query*?

Comment: Você parte de algum dado?

Comment: @Marconi não entendi sua dúvida.

Comment: Digo porque de `2017-07-10 10:11:15` para `2017-07-10 10:11:30` teria intervalo de 15 segundos também.

Comment: @Marconi na verdade, partindo do ultimo registro por exemplo.

Comment: Conseguir fazer em `SQL-Server` partindo da Data Inicial = `2017-07-10 10:11:10`, ajuda você @acklay?

Comment: @Marconi caso tenha alguma coisa que não tenha no MySQL posso dar uma olhada em como adaptar. Provavelmente, digo provavelmente ajuda sim. Manda ai. =D

Comment: Postada, creio eu que é só ajustar a função DATEDIFF @acklay :)

Answer (score 2):

Usando [CTE](http://www.macoratti.net/13/05/sql_cte1.htm) isso é possível a partir do *SQL Server 2005*, está disponível também no [MYSQL](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes/).

**Mas o que vem a ser mesmo Common Table Expression (CTE) ?**

> Uma Common Table Expression (CTE) pode ser vista como um result set
>   temporário que é definido no escopo de execução de uma única instrução
>   SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, ou CREATE VIEW. Uma CTE é muito
>   parecida com uma tabela derivada que não é armazenada como um objeto e
>   que existe apenas durante a execução da consulta. Diferente de uma
>   tabela derivada uma CTE pode ser auto-referenciada e pode ser
>   referenciada várias vezes na mesma consulta.

## INSERT

```
INSERT INTO Table_Data(DATA)
VALUES('2017-07-10 10:11:10'),('2017-07-10 10:11:15'),('2017-07-10 10:11:20'), ('2017-07-10 10:11:25'),('2017-07-10 10:11:30'),('2017-07-10 10:11:35'),('2017-07-10 10:11:40');
```

## Query:

```
WITH DATAS AS
  (SELECT *
   FROM Table_Data
   WHERE DATA = '2017-07-10 10:11:10'
   UNION ALL SELECT TD.Data
   FROM Table_Data TD,
        DATAS D
   WHERE DATEDIFF(SS, D.Data,TD.Data) = 15 )
SELECT *
FROM DATAS
```

**Resultado para a data '2017-07-10 10:11:10':**

```
2017-07-10 10:11:10.000
2017-07-10 10:11:25.000
2017-07-10 10:11:40.000
```

**Resultado para a data '2017-07-10 10:11:15':**

```
2017-07-10 10:11:15.000
2017-07-10 10:11:30.000
```

**NOTA:** *Essa resposta funciona no SQL-Server, a função [DATEDIFF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) é especifica do banco MSSQL, então é necessário adaptar.*

Comment: Vish, estou usando MySQL 5.7... parece que CTE tem para o 8.0... estou analisando aqui pra ver se é possível adaptar. Fiz um teste aqui, tenho 10mil linhas. Talvez dê uma travadinha usando essa abordagem. Localmente durou 3.5784 segundos para retornar os resultados.

Comment: Vish, eu não sabia @acklay, inclusive não tenho MYSQL instalado. Tomara que dê certo ai :)

Comment: @acklay a resposta abaixo atende?

Comment: Esta dizendo a resposta do Djalma?! Aqui comigo não funcionou.

Comment: @acklay sim, pelo que pude perceber não ia funcionar mesmo não. Creio eu que vc vai precisar de alguma coisa recursiva msm. Ou então levar pro lado da aplicação e ajustar lá.

Comment: Fiz uma pergunta no SOzão. Teve uma resposta, porém também não funfou. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419436/how-to-return-some-data-with-time-interval

Comment: O cara fez um join e usa o timestampdiff, que tem o mesmo propósito do DATEDIFF do SQL.

Comment: Entendi, pergunta top essa sua, pena que a minha reposta não pode ajudar. Mas jájá encontra uma solução

Comment: Vou editar e colocar o início dela como está lá no SOzão. Mas desde já agradeço pela força +1.

Comment: Fiz uma pergunta lá no SO DBA também: 
 https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182549/how-to-return-some-data-with-time-interval ... ainda nada de uma solução concreta. Ainda estou fazendo alguns testes.

Comment: @acklay que problemão você arrumou em.

Comment: @acklay porque não faz na aplicação?

Comment: Porque na minha cabeça, fazer no banco seria bem mais fácil. Ainda não tinha pensando em fazer na aplicação. Estou fazendo alguns testes. Criei uma solução temporária usando mod. =D

Comment: Entendi, posta o resultado pra gente ver se encontrar algo =D

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o [SUBDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subdate).

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(primary_key), SUBDATE(data, INTERVAL 15 SECOND)
FROM
    tabela
GROUP BY SUBDATE(data, INTERVAL 15 SECOND)
ORDER BY data DESC
```

Exemplo apicado na versão 5.7. Funcionou e listou os valores com o intervalo a cada 15 segundos com base no último registro. Mas não ficou exatamente as distinção dos segundos como: 00, 15, 30 porque ainda não tive tempo de formatar a saída da informação. Futuramente irei alterar a pergunta

Comment: Você testou isso? Não funcionou aqui comigo. E eu também preciso dos IDs listados na query. Desta forma que esta fazendo, não exibe.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta, conforme seu comentário